# arduino uno interruption code 2 leds 1 switch

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, interruptions

I've tried to make an interruption in my arduino uno board the wired are connected correctly but i don't know what's the wrong with the code .. what i want is that led1 is running at default and when i press the switchbutton it stop the working of the led1 and start to make a loop for the led2 .. i've checked the code several times and i still don't know the mistake in the code

```
int led1 = 13;
int led2 = 12;
int button=0;
boolean x = false ;


void setup() 
{
  pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(button, INPUT);
  attachInterrupt(button, ledchange , CHANGE);
}

void loop() 
{
  digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  //delay(1000);               // wait for 1000 melli-second

}

void ledchange()
{
  x=true;
  digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
  for ( int i=0 ; i<=5 ; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(led2,HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }

}
```

any suggestions ?

Comment: don't use `delay()` in an ISR.

Comment: Are you using D2 and not D0?

Comment: And just as a general principle, don't do lengthy stuff in an ISR. Best off just to set / clear a flag in there, then check the flag in your main loop.

Answer (score 0):

@TOMATO is correct delay won't increment in side an ISR, as all the Interrupts are disabled. Hence it won't exit.

Unless you re-enable interrupts.

```
void ledchange()
{
  interrupts(); // re-enable interrupts so that ms may increase for following delay()
  x=true;
  digitalWrite(led1,LOW);
  for ( int i=0 ; i<=5 ; i++)
  {
    digitalWrite(led2,HIGH);
    delay(1000);
    digitalWrite(led2,LOW);
    delay(1000);
  }

}
```